# Metabox value for post loop?

Tags: custom-field, loop, metabox

I created metabox.If the checkbox is checked if the posts are listed.
How do I browse the posts marked with checkbox ?

[Metabox Code.](http://pasted.co/bc3304ae)

Metabox output:

[image: Metabox Output]

Comment: As they say, 'check the codex'. Have a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Try [WP_Query with custom fields parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys.I did it with **WP_Meta_Query** (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

Solution:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 
             'meta_key' => 'j4cob_yaz_ayarlar_show_on_slider_',
             'meta_value'   => 'show-on-slider',
             'posts_per_page' => 6
             ) ); ?>
   <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
.
Loop
.
<?php endwhile; 
             wp_reset_postdata();
             else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
          <?php endif; ?>
```